# R - Create column from conditional operation over other multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to create a new column with the following logic: for each row if the row name is 's' the new column take the value of the sum of non empty columns (in a subset) unless the sum is zero, in which case it should take the value of the v1 column.

An example of the data.frame

```
  name   year   v1         COL1   COL2 COL3 COL4 COL5 COL6 COL7
 1  S   1960   0.00  0.000000000   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA ...
 2  S   1961   0.00  0.000000000   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA ...
 3  S   1962   0.00  0.000000000   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA ...
 4  S   1963   0.00  0.000000000   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA ...
 5  N   1964   0.00  0.000000000   NA   NA   55   NA   22   NA ...
 6  S   1965  -0.13 -0.160505952   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   45 ...
```

ETC. An example of the code that i was trying:

```
df$nexcol <- 0
df$nexcol[df["name"]=="S"] <-ifelse(rowSums(!is.na(df[df["name"]=="S",5:106]))==0,
                             df[df["name"]=="S","V1"],rowSums(!is.na(df[df["name"]=="S",5:106])))
df$nexcol[df["name"]=="N"] <- 1
```

The expected result is

```
   name   year   v1         COL1   COL2 COL3 COL4 COL5 COL6 COL7 ... nexcol
 1  S   1960   2.00  0.000000000   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA ...    2.00
 2  S   1961   3.00  0.000000000   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA ...    3.00
 3  S   1962   4.00  0.000000000   52   NA   NA   NA   10   NA ...    2
 4  S   1963   2.00  0.000000000   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA ...    2.00
 5  N   1964   3.00  0.000000000   NA   NA   55   NA   22   NA ...    1
 6  S   1965  -0.13 -0.160505952   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   45 ...    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, close to what you have tried but more in `R` way:

```
df$nexcol = rowSums(!is.na(df[5:10]))
df$nexcol = with(df, ifelse(name == 'N', 1, ifelse(nexcol == 0, v1, nexcol)))

df
#   name year    v1      COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4 COL5 COL6 COL7 nexcol
# 1    S 1960  2.00  0.000000   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA      2
# 2    S 1961  3.00  0.000000   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA      3
# 3    S 1962  4.00  0.000000   52   NA   NA   NA   10   NA      2
# 4    S 1963  2.00  0.000000   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA      2
# 5    N 1964  3.00  0.000000   NA   NA   55   NA   22   NA      1
# 6    S 1965 -0.13 -0.160506   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   45      1
```

Or use `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(nexcol = rowSums(!is.na(.[5:10])), 
              nexcol = case_when(.$name == 'N' ~ 1, .$nexcol == 0 ~ .$v1, TRUE ~ .$nexcol))

#   name year    v1      COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4 COL5 COL6 COL7 nexcol
# 1    S 1960  2.00  0.000000   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA      2
# 2    S 1961  3.00  0.000000   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA      3
# 3    S 1962  4.00  0.000000   52   NA   NA   NA   10   NA      2
# 4    S 1963  2.00  0.000000   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA      2
# 5    N 1964  3.00  0.000000   NA   NA   55   NA   22   NA      1
# 6    S 1965 -0.13 -0.160506   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   45      1
```

Comment: thanks it worked! And it make me see other problem. The column V1 was a "factor" in my code so, when it is returned in the second ifelse, the returned value was the factor index (and it happens to be 1 in the particular case that i'm analyzing)